# Python , array wont change after once in iteration(swapping)

Tags: python, arrays

im trying to solve a problem,
But while im debugging , I found that the value of array won't change after once.
Is there something i did wrong in this short 5 line of code??
thanks for the answer in advance.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(5):  
    b, c = map(int, input().split())
    a[a.index(b)], a[a.index(c)] = a[a.index(c)], a[a.index(b)]

print(a)
```

example input:

```
5 4
1 2
3 4
1 4
2 2
```

expected output:

```
3 1 4 2 5
```

my output:

```
1 2 3 5 4
```

Comment: Instead of using `input()`, can you hardcode a known input that fails?

Comment: sorry, I just edited it !

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); don't expect every one of us to type input for you.

Comment: What is this program *supposed* to do?  *Why* do you expect other output?  It obviously works the way you programmed it -- computers are rather annoying in that respect.

Comment: @harveychoi this is actually an interesting question, but you've made it hard to understand. You can show a minimal example with just: `a[a.index(1)], a[a.index(2)] = a[a.index(2)], a[a.index(1)]` — you don't need all the `input()` business — and then simply ask why it is not swapping elements as you might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
for i in range(5):  
    b, c = map(int, input().split())
    b_index = a.index(b)
    c_index = a.index(c)
    a[b_index], a[c_index] = a[c_index], a[b_index]
```

---

here is a piece of code to understand the behavior:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def get_index(i, s):
    idx = a.index(i)
    print(s, i, idx)
    return idx

a[get_index(1, 'left')], a[get_index(2, 'left')] = a[get_index(2, 'right')], a[get_index(1, 'right')]
print(a)
```

output:

```
right 2 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
right 1 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
left 1 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
left 2 0
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

as you can see `get_index(2, 'left')` is not the same with `get_index(2, 'right')`, this shows that `a.index(c)` doesn't have the same value in the left and in the right side of the `=` operator

---

back to your code:

```
a[a.index(b)], a[a.index(c)] = a[a.index(c)], a[a.index(b)]
```

first, it is executed the code from the right side of `=` operator so you have (c, b), then `a[a.index(b)]` will take the value `c`, at this step you have 2 of `c` in your list `a`,  when  `a.index(c)` it is evaluated will return the first `c` found from the left to right,  in the final step you want to set value `b` to where `c` was in the beginning, but now you have 2 of  `c`, if `c` < `b` you will end with the desired output because the method `list.index` will return the position of actual `c`; if `b` < `c` then `b`  will take the place where b was in the beginning and this will result in no change in your list `a`

---

example:

```
case b < c
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] --> swap 2 with 5; b = 2, c = 5
a[a.index(b)], a[a.index(c)] =  5, 2
a[a.index(b)] = 5 --> a = [1, 5, 3, 4, 5]
      -->  a.index(5) --> --> ↑
      ↑
a[a.index(c)] = 2 --> a =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


case b > c
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] --> swap 2 with 5; b = 5, c = 2
a[a.index(b)], a[a.index(c)] =  2, 5
a[a.index(b)] = 2 --> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
      -->  a.index(2) --> --> ↑
      ↑
a[a.index(c)] = 5 --> a =  [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```